# Background blocks particle effects

Tags: ios, swift

I added a background and a explosion particle effect to my app. the background and the sprites work fine together but the explosion effect appears behind the background. The zposition for the background is set to zero, some assistance would be legit.

```
   background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Starfield")
    background.size = CGSize(width: 430, height: 700)
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 )
    self.addChild(background)
    background.zPosition = 0

func explosion(pos: CGPoint) {
    var emitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion.sks")
    emitterNode!.particlePosition = pos
    self.addChild(emitterNode!)
    // Don't forget to remove the emitter node after the explosion
    self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(2), completion: { emitterNode!.removeFromParent() })

}
```

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515948/how-would-i-make-an-explosion-animation-on-ios This might help you.

Comment: Can you post your code that's accomplishing this for better context

Comment: The explosion effect is called when the sprites die.

Comment: The default `zPosition` is `0`. So both your background and your emitter have the same `zPosition`. Either give your emitter a higher `zPosition` - or your background a lower one.

Comment: Thanks originaluser2, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for anyone who needs it.

```
func explosion(pos: CGPoint) {
    var emitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion.sks")
    emitterNode!.particlePosition = pos
    self.addChild(emitterNode!)
    // Don't forget to remove the emitter node after the explosion
    self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(2), completion: { emitterNode!.removeFromParent() })
emitterNode?.zPosition = 2

}
```